# Collision not detected sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-engine

I have a game which has as principal objective collide one object with another. The speed of one of them is higher under some conditions, but this doesn't seem to be the problem since collisions works sometimes with HIGHER speeds and doesn't work with lower speeds.

I have all rigidbodys collision detection as continuous and TimeStep from 0.01 to 0.03 in Time Settings.

This is the code I use to manage collisions. It works normally, but not sometimes as I said before. Any ideas?

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if (other.tag == "Finish") {
            Goal=true;
        }
```

Comment: Define "higher" and "lower" speeds, IIRC, the latest version of physx does some calculations at higher speeds to check if a collision would have occurred by ray casting from the previous position to the current position and checking for hits. How are you moving the rigidbodies?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I move the rigidbodys with:

Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, destiny, speed * Time.deltaTime);

the speed variable fluctuates between 5f and 20f, and it can fail ant 6 or 10...

Comment: If you are directly setting the `Transform.position` then what you are doing is essentially 'teleporting' the GameObject every frame, the best way to move a rigidbody for proper collision detection would be with `Rigidbody.MovePosition` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and let you know (it's late here) thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sounds good! Also, I would recommend starting your scene, then pausing it, and just stepping through the scene frame by frame (use the button to the right of the pause button), and checking that the `transform` is inside the trigger for at least 1 frame. Lastly, I would add `Print("Trigger Enter");` after your if statement to make sure that the issue isn't with the tag detection. Good luck!

Comment: I've tried with your solution but the problem is still here...I've notice that this issue is normally more present on mobile rather than on the editor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120312/discussion-between-user1423168-and-xander-luciano).